# Different logins in different tabs using Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, session

In Google Chrome, is it possible to access a website from two tabs with different logins?

In other words, can different tabs have different sessions?

Screen snapshot of 2 Google Chrome tabs:

[image]

As a workaround, I am using an incognito window to generate a separate session but this limits me to two sessions only.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension available for Chrome called SessionBox which enables you to do this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-free-multi-log/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig

There are probably similar extensions also available if you search for them.